# ActiveRecord query on parent OR query on self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an interesting situation, where I want to list 2 types of `MaintenanceOrders`.

1. For `MaintenanceOrders` that DO have a `rental_item_id` attribute, I want to list them only if the parent `rental_item`'s `order` has a `status_id` of incomplete and if the `MaintenanceOrder` itself has a `status_id` of incomplete.

   `MaintenanceOrder.where.not(rental_item_id:nil).joins(rental_item: [:order]).where("orders.status_id is NULL").where(status_id:nil)`
2. For `MaintenanceOrders` that do NOT have a `rental_item_id` attribute, I just want to list them if the `MaintenanceOrder` itself has a `status_id` of incomplete.

   `MaintenanceOrder.where(rental_item_id:nil).where(status_id:nil)`

So as you can see above, I have the code for both, but I'd like to combine them into a single `#<ActiveRecord::Relation` (not one of those array things). How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for `has_one :through` association http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association

In your MaintenanceOrder class, where you define `has_one :order` add has_one :status, through: :order`. Then you can simply do`MaintenanceOrder.status.present?`